# Array to string conversion Codeignater_3

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a problem in may model, please help me!!!

I have 2 tables in a barrel, one of which contains an id, and another table containing all the columns we need, and the information we need to display in the view.

Model:

```
function get_categories_id_in_tournament($id)
{

    $this->ci->db->SELECT('weight_from AS w_from, weight_to AS w_to, gender AS gen, age_from AS a_from, age_to AS a_to');
    $this->ci->db->FROM('categories');
    $this->ci->db->JOIN('tournament_categories', 'category_id = id');
    $this->ci->db->where('tournament_id', $id);
    $query = $this->ci->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
$data = array(

        'get_categories' => $this->tournaments_model->get_categories_id_in_tournament($id),
    );
```

View:

```
    foreach ($get_categories as $row2)
    {
    echo
    $row2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$data = array(

```
'get_categories' => $this->tournaments_model->get_categories_id_in_tournament($id),
    );
```

$get_categories variable is a multidimensional array, and when you will use foreach loop, then $row also will be a array not a string and echo can print only string value can`t array that`s why its getting this error, so please user **print_r instead of echo inside loop**.